# Replace end string text with new string text

Tags: python-2.7

How to replace just end of text with new text?

From:

```
/var/www/html/file.php 

/home/www/html/data.php
```

To:

```
/var/www/html/module.php 

/home/www/html/module.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility with `str.rsplit()`:

```
l = ['/var/www/html/file.php',
'/home/www/html/data.php']

for item in l:
    print( item.rsplit('/', 1)[0] + '/module.php' )
```

Prints:

```
/var/www/html/module.php
/home/www/html/module.php
```

---

Or using `re`:

```
import re

for item in l:
    print( re.sub(r'(.*/)(.*?)$', r'\1module.php', item) )
```

---

EDIT: To write to file:

```
l = ['/var/www/html/file.php',
'/home/www/html/data.php']

import re

with open('data.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for item in l:
        f_out.write( re.sub(r'(.*/)(.*?)$', r'\1module.php', item) + '\n')
```

Comment: ok this work with `request.get()`, but i try add code for save to txt file not work, i just get null, my code : `open('data.txt', 'a').write(l, re.sub(r'(.*/)(.*?)$', r'\1module.php', item))`

Comment: still not work, can you see this [my example code](https://pastebin.com/sKWm1DaE) ?

Comment: yes work but here im use list of my data with `sys.argv` and my functions `def site(url)`, for my list data, im use in txt file, how can i convert my list data in txt to string?

Comment: @StuartLee I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly.. you can use `str.split` for example to split one string and make list of strings

Comment: here my full code [https://pastebin.com/4RrzYUxu](https://pastebin.com/4RrzYUxu) can you help me for fix this sir?

Comment: @StuartLee Well, you can try this version https://pastebin.com/137GPpLL

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `str.split` & `str.join`.

**Ex:**

```
files = ["/var/www/html/file.php", "/home/www/html/data.php"]
tochange = "module.php"
print(["/".join(f.split("/")[:-1] + [tochange]) for f in files])
```

**Output:**

```
['/var/www/html/module.php', '/home/www/html/module.php']
```

Comment: how if i have more data? like 1000 data with name .php diffrent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in `os` module for manipulating paths:

```
import os

files = ['/var/www/html/file.php', '/home/www/html/data.php']
path_list = map(lambda path: os.path.dirname(path), files)
file_names = ['module.php', 'test.php']
result = [os.path.join(p, f) for p in path_list for f in file_names]
print(result)
```

Output:

> ['/var/www/html/module.php', '/var/www/html/test.php', '/home/www/html/module.php', '/home/www/html/test.php']

Comment: how if i have more data? like 1000 data with name .php diffrent?